# Problem in SQL query. Works for MAX but not for MIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query, which returns the maximum value of a column, separating it by hours and dates.

```
DECLARE @fkTipoDato integer = 2;
DECLARE @fkPlanta integer= 1;
DECLARE @FechaInicio datetime=CAST('2020-27-10 00:00:00' as datetime);
DECLARE @FechaFin datetime=CAST('2020-28-10 00:00:00' as datetime);
 

  SELECT CAST(FechaHora AS DATE) as [Fecha],
        MAX(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 0 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [00:00],
        MAX(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 1 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [01:00],
        MAX(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 2 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [02:00],
        MAX(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 3 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [03:00],
        MAX(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 4 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [04:00],
        MAX(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 5 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [05:00],
        MAX(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 6 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [06:00],
        MAX(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 7 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [07:00],
        MAX(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 8 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [08:00],
        MAX(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 9 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [09:00],
        MAX(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 10 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [10:00],
        MAX(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 11 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [11:00],
        MAX(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 12 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [12:00],
        MAX(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 13 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [13:00],
        MAX(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 14 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [14:00],
        MAX(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 15 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [15:00],
        MAX(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 16 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [16:00],
        MAX(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 17 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [17:00],
        MAX(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 18 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [18:00],
        MAX(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 19 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [19:00],
        MAX(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 20 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [20:00],
        MAX(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 21 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [21:00],
        MAX(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 22 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [22:00],
        MAX(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 23 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [23:00]
   FROM RegistroDatos
   WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato and fk_Planta = @fkPlanta and fechaHora BETWEEN @FechaInicio and DATEADD (day , 1 , @FechaFin)
  GROUP BY CAST(FechaHora AS DATE)
    ORDER BY CAST(FechaHora AS DATE) ASC
```

This way it works correctly, the problem is when instead of looking for the maximum, I look for the minimum in the following way:

```
DECLARE @fkTipoDato integer = 2;
DECLARE @fkPlanta integer= 1;
DECLARE @FechaInicio datetime=CAST('2020-27-10 00:00:00' as datetime);
DECLARE @FechaFin datetime=CAST('2020-28-10 00:00:00' as datetime);
 

  SELECT CAST(FechaHora AS DATE) as [Fecha],
        MIN(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 0 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [00:00],
        MIN(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 1 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [01:00],
        MIN(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 2 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [02:00],
        MIN(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 3 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [03:00],
        MIN(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 4 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [04:00],
        MIN(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 5 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [05:00],
        MIN(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 6 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [06:00],
        MIN(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 7 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [07:00],
        MIN(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 8 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [08:00],
        MIN(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 9 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [09:00],
        MIN(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 10 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [10:00],
        MIN(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 11 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [11:00],
        MIN(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 12 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [12:00],
        MIN(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 13 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [13:00],
        MIN(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 14 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [14:00],
        MIN(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 15 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [15:00],
        MIN(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 16 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [16:00],
        MIN(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 17 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [17:00],
        MIN(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 18 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [18:00],
        MIN(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 19 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [19:00],
        MIN(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 20 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [20:00],
        MIN(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 21 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [21:00],
        MIN(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 22 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [22:00],
        MIN(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 23 THEN Valor ELSE 0 END) AS [23:00]
   FROM RegistroDatos
   WHERE fk_TipoDato = @fkTipoDato and fk_Planta = @fkPlanta and fechaHora BETWEEN @FechaInicio and DATEADD (day , 1 , @FechaFin)
  GROUP BY CAST(FechaHora AS DATE)
    ORDER BY CAST(FechaHora AS DATE) ASC
```

The result I get is:

[Query result: MIN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYoLO.png)

Thank you very much for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `ELSE`:

```
   MIN(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, FechaHora) = 0 THEN Valor END) AS [00:00],
```

You want `NULL` (the default value) so the value is ignored.  By providing `0`, you are assigning a known minimum value.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, that solved it. Greetings